# Deleting a file in eclipse using java

Tags: eclipse, spring, delete-file

I am working on Spring. In that I try to delete the folder named entity in webcontent.But the folder is being deleted only in the temp folder of my project in workspace. In Eclipse the folder is remaining there in the same location. I simply used `file.delete()`.

Any idea?

Comment: What path are you giving ? relative ?

Comment: did you refresh the eclipse navigator after the delete?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which web server you are publishing to, but most web server plugins implement publishing by copying content of your project into another temporary directory, where the content can be assembled into the form expected by the web server (different from the form of the project in Eclipse workspace).

As you found out, deleting files from within your web app doesn't update your project. The synchronization is one-way only. Applications aren't expected to be updating themselves. It isn't a good practice. In production, your app may not even be deployed as a folder. It could be deployed a .war file.

Application data should be written to a folder outside of the application.